# Socket.io-node-react app only showing recent message

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, real-time-data

In my socket-node-react app ,when ever I try to real time chat sometimes all message shows,some times only recent message shows, somwtimes only few of recent messages show in react-scrollable-feed!  It should show all the messages of a chat! please help me.  This is my client side code of singlechat component of where all things are happening

```
singlechat component code:
import React from "react";
import "./SingleChat.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../App";
import { getSender, getFullDetailOfSender } from "../../logic/chatLogic";
import ProfileModal from "../ProfileModal/ProfileModal";
import UpdateGroupModal from "../UpdateGroupModal/UpdateGroupModal";
import axios from "axios";
import ScrollableChat from "../ScrollableChat/ScrollableChat";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const SingleChat = () => {
  const {
    selectedChat,
    setSelectedChat,
    user,
    chats,
    setChats,
    fetchAgain,
    setfetchAgain,
  } = useContext(UserContext);
  // console.log("single user is called, the user",user);
  var selectedChatCompare, socket;
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");
  const [socketConnected, setSocketConnected] = useState(false);
  const [typing, setTyping] = useState(false);
  const [istyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);
  const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5002";


  const fetchMessages = async () => {
    if (!selectedChat) return;

    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        },
      };

      setLoading(true);

      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5002/api/message/${selectedChat._id}`,
        config
      );
      setMessages(data);
      console.log("fetched msg: from single chat", data);
      setLoading(false);

      socket.emit("join chat", selectedChat._id);
    } catch (error) {
      // toast({
      //   title: "Error Occured!",
      //   description: "Failed to Load the Messages",
      //   status: "error",
      //   duration: 5000,
      //   isClosable: true,
      //   position: "bottom",
      // });

      console.log("fetch msg error", error);
    }
  };
  const sendMessage = async (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter" && newMessage) {
      // socket.emit("stop typing", selectedChat._id);

      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
          },
        };
        setNewMessage("");
        const { data } = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:5002/api/message",
          {
            content: newMessage,
            chatId: selectedChat._id,
          },
          config
        );

        setMessages([...messages, data]);
        
        console.log("messages in send msg:", messages);
        socket.emit("new message", data);
 
        // setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, data]);
        // if (data) alert("there is data");
        // console.log("messages", data)

        // setfetchAgain(!fetchAgain)
      } catch (error) {
        // toast({
        //   title: "Error Occured!",
        //   description: "Failed to send the Message",
        //   status: "error",
        //   duration: 5000,
        //   isClosable: true,
        //   position: "bottom",
        // });
        console.log("msg error", error);
      }
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit("setup", user);
    socket.on("connection", () => {
      setSocketConnected(true);
    });
  },);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMessages();

    selectedChatCompare = selectedChat;

  }, [selectedChat]);



  // useEffect(() => {
  //   socket.on("message received", (newMessageReceived) => {
  //     if (
  //       !selectedChatCompare || 
  //       selectedChatCompare._id !== newMessageReceived.chat._id
  //     ) {

  //       //   }
  //     } else {
  //       setMessages([...messages, newMessageReceived]);
 
  //     }
  //   });
  // });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message received", (newMessageReceived) => {
      if (
        !selectedChatCompare || // if chat is not selected or doesn't match current chat
        selectedChatCompare._id !== newMessageReceived.chat._id
      ) {
      //   if (!notification.includes(newMessageRecieved)) {
      //     setNotification([newMessageRecieved, ...notification]);
      //     setFetchAgain(!fetchAgain);
      //   }
      } else {
        console.log("messages in message:", messages);
        setMessages([...messages, newMessageReceived]);
        // setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessageReceived]);
      }
    });
  });




  const typingHandler = (e) => {
    setNewMessage(e.target.value);
  };


  return (
    <div
      className="single-chat-main flex-column px-2 pb-2"
      style={{
        fontFamily: "Work sans",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        background: "",
      }}
    >
      <div className=" ">
        {selectedChat ? (
          <>
            <div
              className=" d-flex "
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Work sans",
                width: "100%",
                background: "",
              }}
            >
              <button
                className="  d-flex p-2 d-md-none btn  justify-content-start "
                onClick={() => setSelectedChat("")}
              >
                {" "}
                <i
                  class="fa fa-arrow-left"
                  style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
                ></i>{" "}
              </button>

              {!selectedChat.isGroupChat ? (
                <div
                  style={{ width: "100%", background: "" }}
                  className="d-flex"
                >
                  <h3 className=" justify-content-center align-items-center p-4  text-secondary">
                    {" "}
                    {getSender(user, selectedChat.users)}
                  </h3>

                  <ProfileModal
                    className=" "
                    user={getFullDetailOfSender(user, selectedChat.users)}
                    Eyeiconshow={true}
                  >
                    {" "}
                  </ProfileModal>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <h3 className=" p-4  justify-content-between text-secondary">
                    {" "}
                    {selectedChat.chatName.toUpperCase()}
                  </h3>
                  <UpdateGroupModal
                    fetchMessages={fetchMessages}
                  ></UpdateGroupModal>
                </>
              )}
            </div>

            <div
              style={{ height: "", minHeight: "67vh", width: "100%" }}
              className="  flex-column justify-content-end  msg-box  pb-0"
            >
              {loading ? (
                <div
                  style={{ minHeight: "50vh" }}
                  className=" d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-center"
                >
                  {" "}
                  <div
                    class="spinner-border  "
                    style={{ width: "5rem", height: "5rem" }}
                    role="status"
                  >
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className="  messages">
                  {" "}
                  <ScrollableChat messages={messages}></ScrollableChat>
                </div>
              )}

              <input
                style={{ width: "100%", heigh: "100%" }}
                className=""
                type="text"
                onChange={typingHandler}
                placeholder="Enter a message"
                value={newMessage}
                onKeyDown={sendMessage}
              />
              {/* </form> */}
            </div>
          </>
        ) : (
          <div
            style={{ minHeight: "82vh", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
            className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
          >
            <h2 className=" text-center text-secondary">
              Click a chat to start conversation
            </h2>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleChat;
```

this is server side code

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const chatRoutes = require("./routes/chatRoutes");
const messageRoutes = require("./routes/messageRoutes");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

connectDB();
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/chat", chatRoutes);
app.use("/api/message", messageRoutes);

app.get("/api/chats", async (req, res) => {
  res.send(chats);
});

app.get("/api/chats/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  const singleChat = chats.find((c) => c._id === req.params.id);
  console.log(singleChat);
  res.send(singleChat);
});
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("api is running");
});
const { chats } = require("./data/data");
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

const server = app.listen(PORT, console.log(`server running on ${PORT}`));
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  pingTimeout: 60000,
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    // credentials: true,
  },
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Connected to socket.io");

  socket.on("setup", (userData) => {

    socket.join(userData._id);
    console.log("created room for", userData._id);
    socket.emit("connected");
  });

  socket.on("join chat", (room) => {
    socket.join(room);
    console.log("User Joined Room: " + room);
  });

  socket.on("new message", (newMessageReceived) => {
    var chat = newMessageReceived.chat;

    if (!chat.users) return console.log("chat.users not defined");

    chat.users.forEach((user) => {
      if (user._id == newMessageReceived.sender._id)  { console.log(" user id and newmsg id same!");return;}

      socket.in(user._id).emit("message received", newMessageReceived);
    });
  });
});
```

this is scrollablechat component code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./ScrollableChat.css";
import ScrollableFeed from "react-scrollable-feed";
import {
  getSender,
  getFullDetailOfSender,
  isLastMessage,
  notSameSender,
  isSameSenderMargin,isSameUser
} from "../../logic/chatLogic";

import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../App";
const ScrollableChat = ({ messages }) => {
  const {
    selectedChat,
    setSelectedChat,
    user,
    chats,
    setChats,
    fetchAgain,
    setfetchAgain,
  } = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log("messages from scrollable chat:",messages);
  return (
    <ScrollableFeed className=" scroll-chat ">
      {messages &&
        messages.map((m, i) => (
          <div  className="  d-flex "style={{ display: "flex" ,overflow:"hidden"}} key={m._id}>
            {(notSameSender(messages, m, i, user._id) ||
              isLastMessage(messages, i, user._id)) ? (
              
                <div style={{height:"auto"}}>
                  {" "}
                  <img src={user.pic} alt="Avatar" class="avatar" />
                </div>
            
            ): <div style={{    width:"20px",
           
              borderRadius:"50%"}}></div>}
            <span
              style={{
                backgroundColor: `${
                  m.sender._id === user._id ? "#BEE3F8" : "#B9F5D0"
                }`,
                marginLeft:  isSameSenderMargin(messages, m, i, user._id)  ,  /* isSameSenderMargin(messages, m, i, user._id), */
                marginTop: isSameUser(messages, m, i, user._id) ? 3 : 10,
                borderRadius: "20px",
                padding: "5px 15px",
                maxWidth: "75%",
                
              }}
            >
              {m.content}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
    </ScrollableFeed>
  );
};

export default ScrollableChat;
```

In my socket-node-react app ,when ever I try to real time chat sometimes all message shows,some times only recent message shows, somwtimes only few of recent messages show in react-scrollable-feed!  It should show all the messages of a chat!